# Java how to transform List<Object> to Page from JPA pagination

Tags: java, spring, arraylist, spring-data-jpa, pagination

I have a problem with my custom search method from Jpa Repository. I implement this method to custom search and in this method I have `List<Car>` from my SQL database and I try to transform it to `Page<Car>` object from JPA pagination & sorting, but the way I'm trying to do this doesn't work. That is just an illusion of pagination because in postman/internet browser i see all elements from list and when I change page and size value in endpoint that change nothing.

Anybody know how to help?

GitHub project: https://github.com/s0bieskii/DemoCarRental

My endpoint from controller:

```
@GetMapping("/find")
ResponseEntity<Page<CarDTO>> readAllCarsFiltered(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page,
                                                 @RequestParam(defaultValue = "5") int size,
                                                 Pageable pageable,
                                                 @RequestParam(required = false) String brand,
                                                 @RequestParam(required = false) String model,
                                                 @RequestParam(required = false) String type,
                                                 @RequestParam(required = false) Integer registrationYear,
                                                 @RequestParam(required = false) String color,
                                                 @RequestParam(required = false) String fuel,
                                                 @RequestParam(required = false) String transmission,
                                                 @RequestParam(required = false) String doors,
                                                 @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "9999999999") double price) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(carService.customerSearch(pageable,
            brand, model, type, registrationYear, color, fuel, transmission, doors, price));
}
```

My service:

```
public Page<CarDTO> customerSearch(Pageable pageable, String brand, String model, String type, Integer registrationNumber, String color,
                                   String fuel, String transmission, String doors, double price){

    return carRepository.search(pageable, brand, model, type, registrationNumber, color, fuel, transmission, doors, price)
            .map(car -> carMapper.carToDto(car));
}
```

My custom search method from `RepositoryImplementation`:

```
 @Override
    public Page<Car> search(Pageable pageable, String brand, String model, String type, Integer registrationYear, String color,
                            String fuel, String transmission, String doors, double price) {
        int var = 0;
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Car> query = cb.createQuery(Car.class);
        Root<Car> car = query.from(Car.class);
        query.select(car);
        Predicate predicate = cb.greaterThan(car.get("id"), var);

        if (brand != null) predicate = cb.and(predicate, cb.equal(car.get("brand"), brand));
        if (model != null) predicate = cb.and(predicate, cb.equal(car.get("model"), model));
        if (type != null) predicate = cb.and(predicate, cb.equal(car.get("type"), type));
        if (registrationYear != null)
            predicate = cb.and(predicate, cb.equal(car.get("registrationNumber"), registrationYear));
        if (color != null) predicate = cb.and(predicate, cb.equal(car.get("color"), color));
        if (fuel != null) predicate = cb.and(predicate, cb.equal(car.get("fuel"), Fuel.stringToFuelEnum(fuel)));
        if (transmission != null)
            predicate = cb.and(predicate, cb.equal(car.get("transmission"), Transmission.stringToTransmissionEnum(transmission)));
        if (doors != null) predicate = cb.and(predicate, cb.equal(car.get("doors"), doors));
        if (price != 0) predicate = cb.and(predicate, cb.lessThan(car.get("price"), price));
        //predicate = cb.and(predicate, cb.equal(car.get("available"), available));
        List<Car> carList=entityManager.createQuery(query.where(predicate)).getResultList();

        return new PageImpl<Car>(carList, pageable,carList.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using Querydsl instead of writing all this yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do custom queries and want to use Pageable, it's up to you to implement a logic to create a paging for your result list. In your case you aren't doing that so it's probably (you said it isn't working, but didn't say what isn't working so I can only guess) just returning the entire result list without paging applied.

A simple solution would be to use `sublist` and use the result of that operation as your parameter for `PageImpl`. Big problem is that you are still getting the entire result list from the database in the background which creates uneceassary overhead.

You could also adjust your query using

```
em.createQuery(query.where(predicate))
      .setFirstResult(offset)
     .setMaxResults(limit)
     .getResultList()
```

Now the paging is done in the database which is a lot better.

Or you save yourself some trouble and use Springs `Specification` interface instead of creating your own search method.

First your `CarRepository` needs to extend `JpaSpecificationExecutor`. Now spring will generate a `findAll(Specification, Pageable)` method for your repository.

Second step is to create your search specification:

```
public class SearchSpecification implements Specification<Car> {
    private final String brand;
    private final String model
    private final String type
    private final Integer registrationYear
    private final String color
    private final String fuel
    private final String transmission
    private final String doors
    private final double price

    // constructor & maybe getter
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Car> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        // Create your search predicate
    }
}
```

Now you can simply call `carRepository.findAll(new SearchSpecification (/* parameters */), pageable);` and spring does the paging for you.

Comment: thanks a lot that work for me :)